# Call data back from AJAX

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have a script which saves canvas PNGs to a directory and I need the URL to save on the server.

When I submit, the image saves but the server remains empty. I am trying to return error messages but I am receiving nothing.

JAVASCRIPT:

```js
function doodleSave() {
 
 
 var drawing   = document.getElementById("doodle-canvas");
 var drawingString =  drawing.toDataURL("image/png");
 var postData  = "canvasData="+drawingString;
 
 var ajax    = new XMLHttpRequest();
 
 ajax.open("POST", 'http://www.website.com/php/doodleSave.php', true);
 ajax.onreadystatechange= function() {
  if (ajax.readyState === 4) //If it ran smoothly

  
    {$("#doodle-submit-button").html("...");}
  
  
 };
 ajax.send(postData);
 
 ajax.success(function(data) {
  
  {$("#doodle-submit-button").html(""+data+"");}
  
 });
 
}
```

PHP:

```html
<?php
session_start();

if (isset($GLOBALS["HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA"])) {

   $rawImage  = $GLOBALS['HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA'];
   $removeHeaders = substr($rawImage, strpos($rawImage, ",")+1);
   $url   = md5(uniqid(rand(), true));
   $decode   = base64_decode($removeHeaders);
   $fopen   = fopen('../images/external/doodles/'.$url.'.png', 'wb');
   fwrite($fopen, $decode);
   fclose($fopen);


   //ADD POST TO DATABASE WITH USER'S ID

   /* AUTOMATED VARIABLES */
   $unique_user_id = $_SESSION['unique_user_id'];
   $unique_post_id = md5(uniqid(rand(), true));
   $timestamp  = time();
   $nature   = "doodle";
   $imageUrl  = 'images/external/doodles/'.$url;


   try
   {

    $stmt = $pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO `(table name)` (unique_user_id, unique_post_id, nature, image_url, timestamp) VALUES(:unique_user_id, :unique_post_id, :nature, :image_url, :timestamp)");
    $stmt->bindParam(":unique_user_id",$profile_unique_user_id);
    $stmt->bindParam(":unique_post_id",$unique_post_id);
    $stmt->bindParam(":nature",$nature);
    $stmt->bindParam(":image_url",$imageUrl);
    $stmt->bindParam(":timestamp",$timestamp);

      if($stmt->execute())
      {
       echo "uploaded";
      }
      else
      {
       echo "Could not upload";
      }

    }
    catch(PDOException $e){
     echo $e->getMessage();
    }
 }

?>
```

Comment: I didn't want "../" to show up in the database. I have included my database connection file in the PHP but still not working.

Comment: I'm not an expert but try removing the ' and brackets from your table name in your insert to and seperate your Table from your values by declaring VALUE ?

The ones I have working look like "INSERT INTO table (value,value,value) VALUE (:value, :value, :value)

Comment: $stmt = $pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO posts (unique_user_id, unique_post_id, nature, image_url, timestamp) VALUE (:unique_user_id, :unique_post_id, :nature, :image_url, :timestamp)");

Comment: Is there a way I can get the PDO errors to see what's going wrong?

Comment: some of the best catching tools on top of the page :) `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1); ini_set('log_errors',1);` EDIT: beat by @Alex for the PDO, was looking for the link :)

Comment: alongside OldPadawans comment http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.errorinfo.php

Comment: I am still receiving no error